# differential geometry applied to Biology

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, applications, biology

I'm looking for current areas of research which apply techniques from differential geometry to biological processes. I'm (scantly) aware of a handful of applications to cell science and microbiology, but I've heard almost nothing of differential geometric methods in say ecology or evolution. Any sort of reference (textbook, paper, researcher, etc) would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you'll have more success over at [MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/) with that question.

Comment: Check out the work of James White and William Pohl on twist and writhe and the explanations of the mathematics of DNA replication.

Comment: Now posted on [mathoverflow.se]: [Differential Geometry applied to biology](https://mathoverflow.net/q/339895)

Answer (score 3):

As you are aware, it is somewhat common to characterize molecular/cellular biology (e.g., modelling cell membranes, protein surfaces, organelle geometry, DNA folding, etc...) or physiology (e.g., [here](https://www.pnas.org/content/109/24/9248.short)) with differential geometry, since one is describing a physically curved surface (i.e., the geometry is "real").

However, (differential) geometry in ecology and/or evolution is necessarily more abstract, since the models tend to be either probabilistic or based on differential equations (or both) of abstract variables. One issue is that not only would a geometric model need to be a good descriptor of the problem, but it would also have to be useful (e.g., provide some intuition/insight that the other description cannot). For instance, diffusion models are not uncommon in ecology, and they can be transformed into "simpler" diffusions on a Riemannian manifold, where the metric tensor is closely related to the diffusivity tensor of the Fokker-Planck equation (or diffusion coefficient of the equivalent Ito process it describes). However, I guess this kind of approach simply doesn't yield enough additional insight for it to be common. Maybe someone who knows the field better than I do can comment on why.

Nevertheless, I've seen a couple applications:

1. Work from [Peter Antonelli](http://www.math.ualberta.ca/Antonelli_P.html) applies differential geometric methods to ecology and evolution, and has quite a few papers in the area. He seems to heavily utilize Finsler manifolds and stochastic processes. For instance:

   - Antonelli et al, *Gradient-Driven Dynamics on Finsler Manifolds: The Jacobi
     Action-Metric Theorem and an Application in Ecology*, 2014
   - Antonelli and Zastawniak, *Fundamentals of Finslerian diffusion with applications*, 2012
2. There is work on evolutionary modelling using differential geometry, by "smoothing" the discrete space of alleles (modelling evolution as continuous). There are also interesting links to information geometry (where one views a space of probability distributions as a Riemannian manifold) in this case. Check out these (and their citers & citations):

   - Shahshahani, *A new mathematical framework for the study of linkage and selection*, 1979
   - Harper, *Information Geomtry and Evolutionary Game Theory*, 2009

Answer (score 2):

The 32 citations in this paper may help:

> Wei, Guo-Wei. "Mathematics at the eve of a historic transition in biology." *Computational and Mathematical Biophysics* 5, no. 1 (2017).
>   [PDF download](https://www.degruyter.com/downloadpdf/j/cmb.2017.5.issue-1/mlbmb-2017-0009/mlbmb-2017-0009.pdf).
>
> ---
>
> [image]

---

Comment: It is unclear to me if any of the references there are related to differential geometry (rather than, say, combinatorial geometry, discrete differential geometry or topology).

Comment: Certainly not all 32 references. Maybe: [15] G. W. Wei. Dfferential geometry based multiscale models. Bulletin of Mathematical Biology, 72:1562 – 1622, 2010. [18] Z. Chen, Shan Zhao, J. Chun, D. G. Thomas, N. A. Baker, P. B. Bates, and G. W. Wei. Variational approach for nonpolar solvation
analysis. Journal of Chemical Physics, 137(084101), 2012.  [6] Beibei Liu, Bao Wang, Rundong Zhao, Yiying Tong, and Guo Wei Wei. ESES: software for Eulerian solvent excluded surface.
Journal of Computational Chemistry, 38:446–466, 2017. But you are right, that there is quite a mix in all those references.